# Problem Analysis - Answer but no procedure - Finding Isogonal Trajectories.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I stumbled with this problem in a notebook that has been bothering for the whole day(actually 4)...The answer is written but there's no explanation nor a steb-by-step procedure or anything. If you know how to analyse the problem and create an equation from this, I will be very grateful!

Find the isogonal trajectories that form 45 degrees with  y^2 = 4ax

Answer: Log(2x^2 + xy + y^2) + 6/root(7)(tan^-1(x+2y/root(7)x) = C
.This answer is one of 2 possibilities.

Comment: What does 45 deg y^2 = 4ax mean?

Comment: @Paul
What I mean is, find the trajectories that form 45 degrees with y^2 = 4(ax)

Answer (score 3):

Isogonal trajectories can be found from the equation
$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{y_1'-y'}{1+y_1' y'}, \tag{1}$$
where $y_1$ is the original equation and $y$ is the family of curves isogonal to $y_1$ with an angle $\alpha$. We are given the parabola $y^2=4ax$. Differentiation gives

$$2yy'= 4a. \tag{2}$$

From the original equation, we find that

$$a=\frac{y_2}{4x},\text{ } x \neq 0 \tag{3}.$$

Substituting $(3)$ into $(2)$, we have 
$$y_1'= y' = \frac{y}{2x}.\tag{4}$$

We are given that $\alpha = \pi/4$ so $\tan(\alpha) = 1$. After substituting $\tan(\alpha) = 1$ and $(4)$ into $(1)$, we obtain the differential equation

$$1=\frac{\frac{y}{2x}-y'}{1+\frac{y}{2x}y'}=\frac{y-2xy'}{2x+yy'}. \tag{5}$$

We can express (5) as

$$(2x-y)\,dx+(y+2x)\,dy=0. \tag{6}$$

This is a homogeneous differential equation so the substitution $y=ux, \, dy=u \, dx + x\,du$ will transform $(6)$ into an equation separable in $u$ and $x$. After substitution and simplification, we have

$$-\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{u +2}{u^2 + u + 2}\,du \tag{7}.$$

Integration of $(7)$ yields
$$-\ln|x|=\frac{1}{2}\ln|u^2+u+2|+\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}\arctan\left(\frac{2u+1}{\sqrt{7}}\right) + C,$$
which we write in the form
$$\ln|x^2u^2+ux^2+2x^2|+\frac{6}{\sqrt{7}}\arctan\left(\frac{2u+1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)= C. \tag{8}$$
We now transform $(8)$ from being in $u$ to being back in $y$ by recalling $u=y/x$. Therefore, we finally obtain
$$\ln|2x^2+xy+y^2|+\frac{6}{\sqrt{7}}\arctan\left(\frac{x+2y}{x\sqrt{7}}\right)= C.$$